# User activity algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. Here it goes, I am looking to calculate a user activity score for a game.

Consider this:

1. User A wants to attack a User B...Z
2. Users B....Z can attack any of Users A...Z

I need a way to **sort** Users B...Z to User A, so they can choose who to attack. We want to make sure that everyone gets to play this game. Which means each user gets advertised as a potential opponent to user A, based on a score determined by:

1. The user B...Z has already been attacked (this user's score should drop, because we want to display someone who hasn't been attacked)
2. User B...Z responds to the attack (this user's score should increase, since they actually are playing the game)

What is the simplest algorithm to calculate such a score?

Comment: huh? What do you mean priority queue?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest algorithm is a simple formula:

Rank = weight1 * TimesResponded - weight2 * TimesAttacked

In which both weights are positive constants, which you can adapt to change the gameplay a little bit.